# Pareto 2 distribution

Tags: distributions, pareto-distribution

I am bit confused between Pareto and Pareto Type II distribution. In the **actuar** library (page 64), details of pareto distribution are given. However, in the end, it is mentioned that "Distribution also known as the Pareto Type II or Lomax distribution". So is it that Pareto is same as Pareto II. I understand it shouldn't be.

For a given data, how do I estimate the parameters for Pareto (Type II) distribution? and using these estimated parameters, how do I use distribution fucntion, quantile function and random no generation function for Pareto (type II distribution)?